Trying to understand the process of Resolving Merge Conflicts with Eclipse/egit
On the project that I am working on now, we are doing mostly Java development using Eclipse, egit, and also Bitbucket.
Because multiple developers are working on the same file simultaneously, I am constantly (basically every time I do a commit/PR) getting merge conflicts, which I haven't really haven't had to deal with before, so, honestly, I am struggling with handling and "resolving" the conflicts.
When I get a merge conflict, Bitbucket says to:
Checkout the source branch and merge in the changes from the target branch. Resolve conflicts.

git checkout dev/55039
git pull origin rel/7.1

After I run those 2 git commands, in Eclipse, I typically see several files appear in Staged Changes and usually 1 or 2 files in Unstaged Changes.
If I click on a file Unstaged Changes, I get the pane with a file from my branch and the other pane shows the conflicting file from another PR.
Parts of the files are marked in different colors (red, blue, gray), and I think those are marking blocks of code that are in different states of conflict vs. non-conflict?
I think that my problem is that I don't understand what the goal is.  I mean I know I need to resolve/remove the conflicts but I am having a hard time understanding what I need to do to accomplish that, so I was wondering if someone could point me to a good source to get an understanding about that, specifically with Eclipse and egit?
For example, with the 2 panes, and say there is a big chunk of lines in the right pane that is blue.  Should I copy those lines from the right pane to the left pane?  Or not?
What is the "end state" that I want to get to in order to "resolve" the conflict?

If you run Git commands outside of Eclipse, make sure to do a refresh afterwards (e.g, by hitting the Refresh (F5) button in the Git Staging view). But better learn what these commands mean and how to do these commands in Eclipse. The documentation on how to merge in Eclipse can be found here: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/Tasks.html#Merging

howlger - I was able to get my merge conflict resolved based on the info you posted.  Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?  Thanks!

The documentation on how to merge in Eclipse can be found in Help > Help Contents: EGit Documentation > EGit User Guide > Tasks > Merging
If you run Git commands outside of Eclipse, make sure to do a refresh afterwards (e.g. in the Git Staging view, by hitting the Refresh (F5) button). But better learn what these commands mean and how to do these commands in Eclipse.
